# wired behavior of failureThreshold value

Tags: kubernetes

I am facing a strange issue with failureThreshold value for a pod. Here is the particular block of problem:

```
readinessProbe:
  enabled: true
  httpPort: 12987
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 30
  timeoutSeconds: 10
  failureThreshold: 1
```

if its value is 1 then container starts successfully but if its value is 2 then it keeps on restarting. Does anyone has clue, why this is happening?

We are on k8s version: v1.12.3-1+fee411aca93f0e

Same configuration runs fine in other (dev) kubernetes cluster so, I can assume its not a code issue.

Comment: Hi, can you provide more information such as `kubectl describe pods $POD_NAME` or  the status part of the yaml `kubectl get pods $POD_NAME -o yaml`

Comment: why your keyname is `httpPort` ?

Comment: @SureshVishnoi, yes, key name id httpPort. Apologies I can't provide yaml file. Seems like `failureThreshold` for `readinessProbe` and `livenessProbe` in these clusters have to be in sync, which is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Change selector **httpPort** to **port**.

Defaults value of **failureThreshold** is to **3**. Minimum value is **1**.
So it is natural that your containers will be restarted beacuse you increased this value.

Take notice that value **initialDelaySeconds** is the same in your case as **timeoutSeconds**. 
Try to increase **initialDelaySeconds**.

Comment: we are fine with initialDelaySeconds and also with failureThreshold value. We face issue if  failureThreshold value is not same in both `readinessProbe` and `livenessProbe`.

Comment: Is it still a problem ?

Comment: No, it got solved by syncing failureThreshold for readinessProbe and livenessProbe in these clusters.